# Reduce Image Collection to Sum when Image do not always overlap in Google Earth Engine or rgee?

Tags: r, rgee

I am trying to generate a single image that is the sum of 16 images. Some of the pixels in the 16 individual images do not overlap with each other.

I have tried

```
ColG2 <- ee$ImageCollection(list(low13g2,high13g2,low14g2,high14g2,low15g2,
                                 high15g2,low16g2,high16g2,low17g2,high17g2,
                                 low18g2,high18g2,low19g2,high19g2,low20g2,
                                 high20g2))
ColG2$getInfo()
Map$addLayers(ColG2)
sG<-ColG2$reduce(ee$Reducer$sum())


sGvis <- list(
  min = 0, 
  max = 80000,
  palette = mypalette,
  opacity=1,
  bands="band1_sum"
)

Map$addLayer(
  eeObject = sG,
  visParams = sGvis,
  name = "sum_g",legend=TRUE)
```

When I map ColG2, I see a map of all the layers. When I try to may sG, the map is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The values you get out from the summed up Image Collection are probably higher than the max you have specified in `sGvis`. Try to increase the max by a lot and see if the values start to appear, or leave it out completely if that is possible in `rgee`.